# how to recover /etc/udev/rules.d file structure?

Tags: command-line, filesystem, directory, udev, mkdir

To troubleshoot driver issues I decided on renaming

```
/etc/udev/rules.d
```

into

```
/etc/udev/rules.d.gold
```

A brilliant idea, because now I am unable to revert my changes:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory rules.d : file exists
```

**original state**

```
ls -la
total 32
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Fev  8 12:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 150 root root 12288 Fev  8 11:15 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Abr 12  2016 hwdb.d
-rw-r--r--   1 user user   435 Dez 14  2017 rules.d        <- A FILE
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Fev  5 18:59 rules.d        <- A FOLDER
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   153 Abr 12  2016 udev.conf
```

**current state**

```
ls -la
total 32
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Fev  8 12:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 150 root root 12288 Fev  8 11:15 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Abr 12  2016 hwdb.d
-rw-r--r--   1 user user   435 Dez 14  2017 rules.d        <- A FILE
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Fev  5 18:59 rules.d.gold   <- A FOLDER
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   153 Abr 12  2016 udev.conf
```

Originally, there was a file and a folder with the same name. I cannot recreate that [because it is not possible to create a file and a folder with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496897/mkdir-p-fails-when-directory-exists).

Now, what?
My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

---

**Edit:**

Looking into my virtual installation of Ubuntu 18.4 the file `rules.d` does not exist.

I am not sure what this file is doing in my host system, perhaps it should not be there. The content of the file is:

```
# version 0002
ATTR{idVendor}=="03fd", ATTR{idProduct}=="0008", MODE="666"
ATTR{idVendor}=="03fd", ATTR{idProduct}=="0007", MODE="666"
ATTR{idVendor}=="03fd", ATTR{idProduct}=="0009", MODE="666"
ATTR{idVendor}=="03fd", ATTR{idProduct}=="000d", MODE="666"
ATTR{idVendor}=="03fd", ATTR{idProduct}=="000f", MODE="666"
ATTR{idVendor}=="03fd", ATTR{idProduct}=="0013", MODE="666"
ATTR{idVendor}=="03fd", ATTR{idProduct}=="0015", MODE="666"
```

Comment: As you noted yourself, the "original state" is not possible (barring filesystem corruption - not even sure about then). Perhaps your original `ls` command missed something such as a trailing space or other non-printing character in one or other of the names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In /etc folder there is a naming convention - `.d` in directory names means directory of files.
For example - compare `/etc/apt/sources.list` (file) with `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` (directory with `*.list` files). Such naming is used for udev too:

> ```
> $ ls /etc/udev/ -d
> /etc/udev/
>
> $ ls /etc/udev/rules.d/ -d
> /etc/udev/rules.d/
> ```

Then about restoration - we can check which package installs files to `/etc/udev/rules*`:

> ```
> $ dpkg -S /etc/udev/rules*
> udev: /etc/udev/rules.d
> ```

So we need to reinstall `udev` package specifying special `--force-confmiss` option (see [`man dpkg`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/dpkg.1.html)):

> `--force-things`...
> **confmiss**: If a conffile is missing and the  version  in  the  package  did  change, always  install the missing conffile without prompting. This is dangerous, since it means not preserving a change (removing) made to the file.

```
sudo mv /etc/udev /etc/udev.old
apt-get download udev
sudo dpkg --force-confmiss -i udev_*.deb
```

---

Note: you can read more about Udev rules on [ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#About_udev_rules).